# How to emulate a VB6 command button _Click event with python ctypes

Tags: python, winapi, vb6, ctypes

**Bigger picture:**

I have a legacy DLL for interprocess communication (no C source code available) - based on numbered pipes. The DLL uses four main functions:

- open
- close
- read
- write

There are VB6 applications which use this DLL and I want to glue Python 3.6.3 for replacing several ends of the line obsolete communication modules. The pipes work by allowing maximum two subscribers to the same port. Each subscriber has to call open and then when one writes the other reads and viceversa.

**Nitty gritty details:**

I want to create an event listener object in Python that is similar to a VB6 command button handle. This win32 handle is then passed to the open function in the dll as a means to 'register' an entry point (similar to callback concept but not quite) for calling the read function.

The legacy DLL uses following VB6 declaration:

```vb
'************************************************************************************************
' Function OpenPipe/SIOOPEN
'   return value: Id of channel (0,1,2,..)
'   parameters:
'             CommPort - port number.
'             MaxTxBuff - max number of Tx buffers
'             MaxRxBuff - max number of Rx buffers
'             hwndTxIO  - Command key handler no. (Null for no handler)
'             hwndRxIO  - Command key handler no. (Null for no handler),
'             HsemTxIO  - 0 allways
'             HsemRxIO  - 0 allways
'             BuffSize  - max number of bytes per message
'             Log       - Log TX and RX
'************************************************************************************************
Public Declare Function OpenPipe Lib "CommPipe" _
  Alias "_SIOOPEN@36" (ByVal CommPort As Long, _
                       ByVal MaxTxBuff As Long, _
                       ByVal MaxRxBuff As Long, _
                       ByVal hwndTxIO As Long, _
                       ByVal hwndRxIO As Long, _
                       ByVal HsemTxIO As Long, _
                       ByVal HsemRxIO As Long, _
                       ByVal BuffSize As Long, _
                       ByVal Log As Boolean) As Long


'************************************************************************************************
' Function ClosePipe/SIOKILL
'   return value: true - succeded, false - failed
'   parameter: CommChannel - channel no, (use this number to react with open comm ports).
'************************************************************************************************
Public Declare Function ClosePipe Lib "CommPipe" _
  Alias "_SIOKILL@4" (ByVal CommChannel As Long) As Boolean


'************************************************************************************************
' Function ReadPipe/SIOREAD
'   return value: true - succeded, false - failed
'   parameters:
'       CommChannel - channel no.
'       ReadBuff - address of read buffer
'       BuffLen - address of variable contains len of message
'************************************************************************************************
Public Declare Function ReadPipe Lib "CommPipe" _
  Alias "_SIOREAD@16" (ByVal CommChannel As Long, _
                       ByRef ReadBuff As Byte, _
                       ByRef BuffLen As Long, _
                       ByRef CmsApStamp As Long) As Boolean

'************************************************************************************************
' Function WritePipe/SIOWRITE
'   return value: true - succeded, false - failed
'   parameters:
'       CommChannel - channel no.
'       WriteBuff - address of writeread buffer
'       BuffLen - len of message
'************************************************************************************************
Public Declare Function WritePipe Lib "CommPipe" _
  Alias "_SIOWRITE@12" (ByVal CommChannel As Long, _
                        ByRef WriteBuff As Byte, _
                        ByVal BuffLen As Long) As Boolean
```

The VB6 application has a dedicated form with a command button. This button's handle is passed to the open pipe function and it is then used as an event-driven system for having the data available as soon as possible (see **myRx.hWnd** below):

```vb
'CreateConnection FUNCTION
'=====================
'1. establish a connection to the vision computer on a Pipe
'2. establish a connection to the IO card
'If a successful then the function returns 'True'
Private Function CreateConnection(ByVal vPort As Long, _
                                  Optional ByRef vName As String = "", _
                                  Optional vIsMasterPipe As Boolean _
                                  = False) As Boolean
  CreateConnection = False
  myName = vName
  myChannelNo = OpenPipe(vPort, _
                         MAX_OUT_BUFFERS, _
                         MAX_IN_BUFFERS, _
                         0, myRx.hWnd, _
                         0, 0, _
                         MAX_PIPE_BUFFER, _
                         False)
  If (myChannelNo >= 0) Then
    CreateConnection = True
    Call GPipeTrap("CreateConnection OK", myName, "Port", vPort, "Handle", myChannelNo)
  Else 'unsuccessful opening
    Call GPipeTrap("CreateConnection KO", myName, "Port", vPort)
'    MsgBox "Could not open COM port " & CNTPORTNO, key_Critical, "Vision Pipe Error"
  End If
End Function
```

For the work on Python end (3.6.6), I have used the ctypes library. First, declare function prototypes:

```py
  self.hllDll =ctypes.WinDLL(str(dll_target))
    #Open pipe
    self.hllOpenPipeProto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE (
      ctypes.c_long,      # Return type - ID of channel
      ctypes.c_long,    # CommPort
      ctypes.c_long,    # MaxTXBuff
      ctypes.c_long,    # MaxRXBuff
      ctypes.c_long,    # hwndTxIO
      ctypes.c_long,    # hwndRxIO
      ctypes.c_long,    # HsemTxIO
      ctypes.c_long,    # HsemRxIO
      ctypes.c_long,      # BuffSize
      ctypes.c_bool)    # Log
    self.hllOpenPipeParams =   ( 
      (1, "CommPort", 0), 
      (1, "MaxTXBuff", 0),
      (1, "MaxRXBuff", 0),
      (1, "hwndTxIO", 0),
      (1, "hwndRxIO", 0),
      (1, "HsemTxIO", 0),
      (1, "HsemRxIO", 0),
      (1, "BuffSize", 0),
      (1, "Log", 0),)
    self.hllOpenPipe = self.hllOpenPipeProto (("_SIOOPEN@36", self.hllDll), self.hllOpenPipeParams)
    #Close pipe
    self.hllClosePipeProto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE (
      ctypes.c_bool,      # Return type - succeded
      ctypes.c_long)    # Channel number
    self.hllClosePipeParams = (1, "ChannelNumber", 0),
    self.hllClosePipe = self.hllClosePipeProto (("_SIOKILL@4", self.hllDll), self.hllClosePipeParams)
    #Read pipe
    self.hllReadPipeProto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE (
      ctypes.c_bool,    # Return type - Succed or failed
      ctypes.c_long,    # Channel number
      ctypes.c_void_p,    # Read buffer
      ctypes.c_void_p,    # Buffer length
      ctypes.c_void_p)    # CmsApStamp ?
    self.hllReadPipeParams =   ( 
      (1, "ChannelNo", 0), 
      (1, "ReadBuffer", 0),
      (1, "BufferLength", 0),
      (1, "CmsApStamp", 0),)
    self.hllReadPipe = self.hllReadPipeProto (("_SIOREAD@16", self.hllDll), self.hllReadPipeParams)
```

I am able to open the communication pipe by running the following code (however I am setting hwndRxIO to 0 which means no handle):

```py
def __open_pipe(self):
    #Open pipe based on settings
    port=str(self.settings['PORT'])
    self.logger.debug('Opening pipe on port ['+port+']..')
    CommPort = ctypes.c_long (int(port))
    MaxTXBuff = ctypes.c_long (self.MAX_OUT_BUFFERS)
    MaxRXBuff = ctypes.c_long (self.MAX_IN_BUFFERS)
    hwndTxIO = ctypes.c_long (0)
    hwndRxIO = ctypes.c_long (0)
    HsemTxIO = ctypes.c_long (0)
    HsemRxIO = ctypes.c_long (0)
    BuffSize = ctypes.c_long (self.MAX_PIPE_BUFFER)
    Log = ctypes.c_bool (0)

    result=self.hllOpenPipe(   
      CommPort,
      MaxTXBuff,
      MaxRXBuff,
      hwndTxIO,
      hwndRxIO,
      HsemTxIO,
      HsemRxIO,
      BuffSize,
      Log)

    self.logger.debug('Result is ['+str(result)+']')
    self.comm_channel=result
    if self.comm_channel<0:
      self.logger.critical('Could not open pipe on port ['+port+']!')
    else:
      self.logger.info('Pipe ['+str(port)+'] open OK, comm channel ['+str(self.comm_channel)+']')
```

I am able to receive data from applications running on the 'other' side of the line by doing lazy polling in the python script:

```py
while self.running:
  self.logger.debug('Pipe loop')
  ChannelNo = ctypes.c_long (int(self.comm_channel))
  BufferLength = ctypes.c_long (0)
  CmsApStamp = ctypes.c_long (0)
  result=True
  data_buff=[]
  result=self.hllReadPipe(   
    ChannelNo=ChannelNo,
    ReadBuffer=ctypes.byref(self.ReadBuffer),
    BufferLength=ctypes.byref(BufferLength),
    CmsApStamp=ctypes.byref(CmsApStamp))
  if result:
    length=BufferLength.value
    self.logger.info('Data ['+str(self.ReadBuffer.raw[:length])+']. Length ['+str(length)+'] bytes.')
  time.sleep(loop_sleep)
```

Finally restating: how can I create an event listener object in Python which is essentially a starting point for calling the read pipe function that I have already implemented in a lazy polling loop.

EDIT: At Daniel's request, the Spy++ output reveals following messages:

```
<00074> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
<00075> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
<00076> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
<00077> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
<00078> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
<00079> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
<00080> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
<00081> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
<00082> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
<00083> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
<00084> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
<00085> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
<00086> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
<00087> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
<00088> 000B049A P WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:0000 wID:4 hwndCtl:001D02E4
```

How to use ctypes to obtain a hwndCtl that i can link to a Python function?

Comment: I would start Spy++ and look up which messages show up. I suppose it would be WM_COMMAND with BN_CLICKED.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I added the messages at the end of my question.

Comment: You need to create a form with a button (I think it even could be hidden). Give `hwnd` of the button to the `OpenPipe`. In the form's windows procedure handle WM_COMMAND message with control id equal 4 and notify code equal 0 (BN_CLICKED is defined as 0 in winuser.h).